# Text Analysis to Solve Multiple Choice Exams

Tags: text-analysis

Given a text book and a set of multiple choice questions based on the given text book, in digital form of course, any thoughts on how to have a computer solve the questions?

I was thinking something along the lines of simple word association(ie if certain words in the answer are near words in the question and somehow minimizing that). I know there are a lot more techniques in data analysis out there, so feel free to share your thoughts.

No this is not homework or school related at all, I just randomly thought about this on a whim.

Answer (score 0):

This type of task falls under the general area of Natural Language Processing and in particular:

- Information Retrieval
- Question Answering and Summarization

Unfortunately while the first is somewhat easier to tackle, the latter is quite a thought subject, even when the questions domain is somewhat well defined.